# How to update all users from an array of objects in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to update all users from an array in mongoose, but I don't know how to do that.

I'm parsing all users from MongoDB database to an array, then I'm editing values in this array and I need to save array back to the database.

Parsing all users from the database:

```js
let users = []
async function loadUser() {
  users = await User.find({}) // User is Schema
}
```

Then I'm trying to save all of them, but it isn't working.

```js
async function saveUsers () {
  users.forEach(user => { // maybe there's other way to do save, but I don't found it.
    User.updateOne(user, user, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use forEach as follow:

```
users.forEach(function(user)){
    User.update({"_id": user._id}, {"$set": {"value": user.value }}, callback);
});
```